# Recive REST and Response http codes in Python

Tags: python, rest, http-status-codes

I want to make very simple application in Python which:

1. When REST calls PUT/DEL/GET are recived than response code is 200
2. When REST call create is recived than response code is 201

I tried with sockets but I don't know how to send 201.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an existing web framework such as Flask or Django.  Doing this by yourself with sockets is way too much work, it's not worth it.

Comment: +1 for Flask. Django is unnecessarily high level for these kinds of simple applications.